# hardhat test fails to invoke with hardhat-gas-reporter

Tags: hardhat, unittesting

I was trying to run the tests, but it always comes back with `nativeNC failed` when `hardhat-gas-reporter` is used.
There is no problem with the `localhost` network, that I can deploy and invoke functions from `hardhat console`. So that means its something specific to the hardhat-gas-reporter setup.

Any idea?

```
$ npx hardhat --network localhost test
An unexpected error occurred:

TypeError: nativeNC failed:


    at createInvalidReporterError (D:\development\carbon\cct\node_modules\mocha\lib\errors.js:207:13)
    at Mocha.reporter (D:\development\carbon\cct\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:343:17)
    at new Mocha (D:\development\carbon\cct\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:196:6)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (D:\development\carbon\cct\node_modules\hardhat\src\builtin-tasks\test.ts:95:21)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (D:\development\carbon\cct\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:219:14)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (D:\development\carbon\cct\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:219:14)
    at Environment.run (D:\development\carbon\cct\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:131:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (D:\development\carbon\cct\node_modules\hardhat\src\builtin-tasks\test.ts:159:28)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (D:\development\carbon\cct\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:219:14)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (D:\development\carbon\cct\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:219:14) {
  code: 'ERR_MOCHA_INVALID_REPORTER',
  reporter: 'D:\\development\\carbon\\cct\\node_modules\\eth-gas-reporter\\index.js'
}
```

hardhat config

```
require("dotenv").config();

require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan");
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require("hardhat-gas-reporter");
require("solidity-coverage");
require('@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades');
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ganache");

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  networks: {
    ropsten: {
      url: process.env.ROPSTEN_URL || "",
      accounts:
        process.env.PRIVATE_KEY !== undefined ? [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY] : [],
    },
    hardhat: {
        blockGasLimit: 13000000,
        gasPrice: 20
    },
  },
  gasReporter: {
    enabled: process.env.REPORT_GAS !== undefined,
    currency: "USD",
    coinmarketcap: process.env.COINMKT_API_KEY,
    url: "http://localhost:8545",
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
  },
};
```

Invoking a deployed contract from hardhat console. The contract address is taken from the output of `npx hardhat node` after `npx hardhat --network localhost run scripts/deploy.js`.

```
npx hardhat --network localhost console
const CCT = await ethers.getContractFactory("CCToken");
cctnft = await CCToken.attach("0xe7f1725e7734ce288f8367e1bb143e90bb3f0512");
await cctnft.uri(0);
```

Comment: How are you invoking functions on the *localhost* network with `hardhat console`? To me it looks like there is no networks.localhost prop in your hardhat config (only ropsten and hardhat). What happens after leaving the network out, e.g. `npx hardhat test` ?

Comment: updated the question with how the locahost node is run and contract is invoked. also, with or without the network, test always fails if I require hardhat-gas-reporter. Otherwise all good, (tests runs, so we know there is no problem with the tests)

Comment: I see now, localhost should connect you to 'http://127.0.0.1:8545' - try changing it to this in the config's gasReporter.url (instead of 'http://localhost:8545')